# SQL Price Scheduling, Select last timestamp thats <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `product_pricing`.

In here, I can add multiple prices for each ID. What differentiates them is the `product_pricing`.`timestamp_valid`...it is what I use to schedule price changes in advance.

```
    SELECT 
        `products`.`wo_id`,
        `products`.`fty_id`,
        `products`.`price` AS price1,

        `product_attributes`.`fty_id`,
        `product_attributes`.`cat_id`,
        `product_attributes`.`design_id`,
        `product_attributes`.`season_id`,

        `products_u_ids`.`u_id`,
        `products_u_ids`.`link_id`,

        `product_designs`.`design_id`,
        `product_designs`.`brand_id`,

        COALESCE(`product_pricing`.`u_id`, NULL) AS price2_u_id,
        COALESCE(`product_pricing`.`currency`, NULL) AS price2_currency,
        COALESCE(`product_pricing`.`price`, NULL) AS price2,
        COALESCE(`product_pricing`.`formula_id`, NULL) price2_formula_id,
        COALESCE(`product_pricing`.`vat_calculated`) AS price2_vat_calculated,
        COALESCE(`product_pricing`.`vat_id`, NULL) AS price2_vat_id,
        COALESCE(`product_pricing`.`timestamp_valid`, NULL) price2_timestamp_valid, 

        COALESCE(`product_price_formulas`.`formula_id`, NULL) AS price2_formula_id,
        COALESCE(`product_price_formulas`.`formula`, NULL) AS price2_formula,

        COALESCE(`global_vat_tariffs`.`vat_id`, NULL) AS price2_vat_id,
        COALESCE(`global_vat_tariffs`.`percentage`, NULL) AS price2_vat_tariff

    FROM `products`

    LEFT JOIN `product_attributes`
        ON `products`.`fty_id` = `product_attributes`.`fty_id`

    LEFT JOIN `products_u_ids`
        ON `product_attributes`.`fty_id` = `products_u_ids`.`link_id`

    LEFT JOIN `product_designs` 
        ON `product_attributes`.`design_id` = `product_designs`.`design_id`

    LEFT JOIN `product_pricing`
        ON `products_u_ids`.`u_id` = `product_pricing`.`u_id`

    LEFT JOIN `product_price_formulas` 
        ON `product_pricing`.`formula_id` = `product_price_formulas`.`formula_id`

    LEFT JOIN `global_vat_tariffs` 
        ON `product_pricing`.`vat_id` = `global_vat_tariffs`.`vat_id`

         LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT `product_pricing`.`u_id`, MAX(`timestamp_valid`) AS MaxDate
            FROM `product_pricing`
            WHERE `product_pricing`.`timestamp_valid` <= UTC_TIMESTAMP
            GROUP BY `product_pricing`.`u_id`
        ) AS temp ON temp.u_id = `product_pricing`.`u_id` AND temp.MaxDate = `product_pricing`.`timestamp_valid`

    WHERE `products`.`wo_id` IN ('028284', '018305', '031536')
```

The SQL I have above, returns all the rows for a given ID, instead of just returning `product_pricing`.``` timestamp_valid``<= UTC_TIMESTAMP() ```.

There is a problem in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

The other thing that this SQL does is, when there isn't anything set for `price2`, it shouldn't break the script, but just return NULL for `price2`. I am solving that by using `COALESCE`.

**This is what I get:**

[image]

**This is what I should get:**
[image]

Assuming the date of the query is 2018-5-7.

Any ideas how to solve this problem with the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: @D-Shih Please take a look at the pics. The problem is, it will return all rows for a given ID. Instead of just one where the `timestamp_valid <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: @Borsn someone with your reputation should already know that we shouldn't post data as images . . . (I didn't downvote)

Comment: I see 2 different values for price2 for 028284 in your first screenshot, do you have 2 entries for 028284 in table `product_pricing`?

Comment: Could it be because your date/time column includes, it looks like, microseconds but UTC_TIMESTAMP does not?

Comment: @Dave No. and that’s not the problem I’m having. It’s reading the date, but not limiting it to 1.

Comment: Looking at the first screenshot again, I meant are there 2 entries for 911544 in table `product_pricing`? A row would be generated for each entry in that table because of your 4th left join.

Comment: @Anch0rman So thats the problem. There are two prices for ID 911544. There should only be one with timestamp 2018-7-5. Like on the second image.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `LEFT JOIN` operation on the subquery containing the timestamp filter you mention. LEFT JOINs retain rows that don't match its ON condition. You might try an ordinary `INNER` join on that subquery; inner JOINs don't retain the rows matching the ON condition.

Comment: So when I use an RIGHT OUTER JOIN, it only displays the ID's that have price2. With an INNER JOIN, its the same deal. Which is why I use LEFT OUTER JOIN. However my problem is that it displays all rows in `product_pricing` for a given ID instead of 1 that matches the timestamp condition.